# Export CSV from phpMyAdmin after using SQL_BIG_SELECTS = 1

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I have the following query which requires `SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS = 1;` to be run before it.

```
SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS = 1;
SELECT uc_products.nid, uc_products.model, uc_products.sell_price
FROM uc_products, node
WHERE node.status = 1
GROUP BY nid
```

This generates exactly what I need in phpMyAdmin. I need to export this as a CSV file but when I go to export, it loses the `SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS = 1;` part of the query and there's no way to add it back in. This means that in the CSV file, I'm getting an error message telling me to use `SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS = 1;` in order to run the query properly.

Has anyone come across this problem before or have any idea how to get around it?

Comment: I managed to do this using MySQL Workbench instead of phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 0):

You can set SQL_BIG_SELECTS in config file or at server startup. It can also be set on a session basis with 'SET SESSION SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1'.